# Unable to get my dynamic CSS working with Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js

Is there a way for me to add dynamic styling depending what the result in my div will be?

I have created a function which will calculate a total number and then change the data property to return either 'Low' or 'Good' depending on what the count will be.

I have two different classes which I have created:

```
.good-result {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.poor-result {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

My dynamic styling looks like this

```
<div class="resultValue">Water intake: <span :class="'Low'?'poor-result' : 'good-result'">{{ resultsWater }}</span></div>
```

If the data property resultsWater says 'Low' I want to try and apply the .poor-result style else the .good-result property, currently it only displays the .poor-result no matter if the divs value is 'Low' or 'Good'

Comment: All non-empty strings are *truthy*, so `'Low'` will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use string interpolation and compare `resultsWater` to `'Low'`:

```
 :class="`${resultsWater === 'Low'?'poor-result' : 'good-result'}">
```